# How do built in macros on Emulators work?

Tags: python, android, android-emulator, adb

I'm building a script to automate some stuff on my Android emulator I'm currently using pyautogui to do it tho it would be nice if there was some sort of way I can directly interact with the emulator without it relying on my mouse
I know there's an option using ADB but that requires the android to be rooted
a lot of android emulators like Nox, Bluestacks, LDplayer have built-in macros that don't require the device to be rooted.

How do these emulators send commands to the emulator is that something I can tap into and send commands through that instead?

Comment: could you please be more specific on the scenarios and the type of commands you need to send to the emulator? thanks!

Comment: @Lino input commands like click(x,y) but without using ADB (requires rooting)or pyautogui (which makes the pc that runs the script unusable while the script is running)

would like to know how to these built-in macros recorder interact with the emulator and if it is possible to tap in and use it with a python script

the built-in one behave like ADB but it doesn't require root and doest take hostile of the mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: These emulator run on virtual machines their macro is sending input command from the virtual machine input API